Is there a way to set a dynamic variable of each value within the range of cells in excel VBA?
I am Trying to create an automation that will set a variable using the data on my Sheet2.
These values (variables) will be used on other code. The list on my Sheet2 changes from time to time. Is this even possible? I am trying to achieve a dynamic list of variables that i can set (by adding/deleting on sheet2) and use/call it anytime on different module.
What I am trying to achieve here is to create a Master Consolidator that will adjust set a variable based on my header of my Masterfile and use it later for other stuff.
Masterfile = where it will be consolidated
FileOne = file where i'll get the data
My current Masterfile have a fixed header and each header is declared as a variable. I used that variable to look if it exist on FileOne when found get the whole data of that column and paste it on the column of my Masterfile.
However this step requires me to declare manually each header as variable and is tedious. if i just try to find the header and consolidate it, I wont be able to use the header/column number for the calculation latter part of the code.
I need to set and declare the following yellow as a variable.


Use a Scripting.Dictionary, or a Collection, or an array.

You can assign the value of a cell to a variable, for multiple cells, you can use an array or dictionary. Is this what you mean? Maybe show us some sample code?

Dim myVar: myVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").value  If you need something more elaborate than that, then please edit your question to describe a specific use case, preferably with some representative VBA...

@TimWilliams how can i set this by the number of list of data on my Sheet2? can i store the list first on an array format then set it as a variable so i can loop declare it?

The main question is if the data on the worksheet contains a variable number of values, how does your code know what each value represents?  Unless it's just a list of the same type of thing, such as a list of states for example, or colors.  Sorry I'm not able to follow your example.

You can read all of the header setup from sheet3 using something like this:
Sub Tester()
     
    Dim headers As Object, k, hdr
    
    Set headers = HeaderConfig()
    
    'list out all headers for all sheets...
    For Each k In headers
        Debug.Print vbLf & k & vbLf & "--------------"
        For Each hdr In headers(k)
            Debug.Print , hdr
        Next hdr
    Next k
    
    'just one sheet
    Debug.Print "---------Sheet2------"
    For Each hdr In headers("Sheet2")
        Debug.Print , hdr
    Next hdr

End Sub

'Read the column header data from Sheet3 and reurn it as a dictionary
'   keys   = worksheet names from row#1
'   values = Collection of column headers for each key
Function HeaderConfig() As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dict As Object, c As Range, h As Range, k As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'where is the data?
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        k = c.Value 'sheet name in Row 1
        If Len(k) > 0 Then
            Set dict(k) = New Collection 'new worksheet name and Collection
            'add all of the column headers to the Collection for this sheet
            For Each h In ws.Range(c.Offset(1), _
                                   ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
                dict(k).Add h.Value
            Next h
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderConfig = dict
End Function


how can i declare the header dynamically using this?
Dim myVar: myVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").value

You cannot dynamically declare variables - you can only dynamically assign values to them.
